# "Cannot find debug adapter for type 'node'. "

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug node script in vs code.

Below is my launch.json -

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "node",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Debug sql report",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/debug_sql.js"
            }
        ]
    }
```

when I run I get an error `Cannot find debug adapter for type 'node'.`

[image: VS Code NodeJs Debugger Error]

My code version is - `Version 1.36.1 (1.36.1)`

Node debugger used to work earlier. But not sure why it is not working now.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Actually uninstalling some of the extensions solved my problem too but I'm not sure which extension that is. emmet, beautify, gdb debugger, tmux, fancy terminal etc. So I'm accepting the answer close to that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a solution, but in my case uninstalling some extensions solved the problem. You/Anyone in future having this problem might try this step as well.

Comment: "uninstalling some extensions" is extremely vague and not in the least helpful

Comment: I guess it's not a particular extension problem, as OP and I had uninstalled different extensions. Maybe it's because of some memory related problem, I don't have an idea. I just wrote what helped me solving this issue.

Answer (score 35):

I had to restart vscode.

Not sure if it's connected but my app crashed because of JavaScript heap out of memory error.

Answer (score 4):

Just install the older 'Node Debug' version from the VSC market place. In my case 1.33 did n't and 1.31 works.

Answer (score 3):

To debug node js on vs-code two extensions are required.

- Node Debug
- Node Debug(legacy)

install or enable both and reload.

[reason for requiring both mentioned here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51572)

> "Node Debug (legacy)" is important because it delegates to "Node Debug" for Node.js versions >= 8.0.
>   Without "Node Debug (legacy)" node debugging is basically disabled because nobody will delegate.

Comment: I've both node debug and legacy. But still the problem persists :(

Comment: Working fine with my vs-code 1.38. node debug, node legacy 1.33.0 and 1.38.4 respectively..

Comment: I remember getting error "extension host stopped unexpectedly". I had to uninstall live share, live share chat and live share audio after which this error disappeared. If you have live share installed, try uninstalling them and restarting vs code. Then try debug.

Comment: I still have the error "extension host stopped unexpectedly" but I don't have live share in my system.

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan could be cz of some other extension.Installing live share caused extension host to stop, which results in node debug not working.

Comment: I simply disabled, then re-enabled both Node Debug and Node Debug(legacy), that fixed it, thx

Answer (score 1):

Seconding the folks who suggested that downgrading would solve the issue. I downgraded from 1.33 to 1.32 and things worked for me once again.

Comment: If you haven't already, please upvote the answer that you are supporting. That could really help other users in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the similar error message when I was trying to debug a C++ application. Googling for it, and I ended up here. Just after setting the launch.json with C++ debugger details, I hadn't restarted my VS Code editor. So after reading the above comments, I just restarted and then was getting continuously error telling Extension Host crashed (or something like that). Opened the Developer Tools window(you will get a button there with the crashed msg) and going to the console window, I could notice a lot of extensions were failing. Went ahead and uninstalled those failing extensions and viola! c++ debugger started working!!! Woowwww...

NOTE: In my case, I guess `Debugger for Java` extension was the culprit, however in that process, I could realize that there were a lot many extensions that I rarely used, and uninstall them. :)

Lesson learned: I was going crazy and had installed many extensions (most of which I seldom use, if at all!!). Now on I should be more careful and organized :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
I´ve to install older version, in my case 1.34

Comment: :( is there no other alternative solution?

Comment: for the moment, i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Try 'npm install' in this folder first. The error occurs if a project is not installed.